# getting error : curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: http in ec2 instance for nvm

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, nvm

when i tried to use command `nvm ls-remote`,  i am getting output : `n/a`, and after then as per the google search they asked me to use `curl $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR` this command i am getting this error `curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: http`, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? any help will be really appreciated.

```
root@ip-********:/home/ubuntu# nvm ls-remote
            N/A
root@ip-********:/home/ubuntu# curl $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: http
root@ip-********:/home/ubuntu#
```

Comment: You could check: is the `$NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR` variable set? For example by using the `echo` command: `echo $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR`. If it is not set, nvm does not know what it's remote is. If it is, you should add the output to your question.

Comment: i am getting this output :  http://nodejs.org/dist